# How to create a desktop shortcut icon for electron-application?

Tags: electron, desktop-application

For my electron application I need a shortcut with icon..

I didn't understand the.ico file and the code where to put it

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your Forge config.

```
module.exports = {
  packagerConfig: {
    asar: true,
    icon: 'images/logo.ico',
},

makers: [
    {
      name: '@electron-forge/maker-squirrel',
      config: {icon: 'images/logo.ico',
      setupIcon: 'images/logo.ico',
},
```

Finally, add this to your main.js file

```
win.setIcon('/images/logo.png') <--- This goes below your win.loadfile
if (require('electron-squirrel-startup')) app.quit(); <--Add this at the bottom
```

That will set up a shortcut on the desktop with the icon. Of course, you can customize the directory to your liking.